# Jenkins, assigning jobs between nodes

Tags: jenkins

I have Jenkins set up with 3 nodes (build-01, build-02 and build-03), labeled with the "build" label , and a Freestyle-type project configuration, in which "Restrict where this project can be run" is set to "build".
When I start a project, it runs OK on build-01, however, when I start another project (with different parameters), it is queued by Jenkins to the same node, even if two other nodes are idle.

How could I configure Jenkins to assign a project to a next idle node?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you added label *build* in the configuration for all nodes: https://jenkins.domain.com/computer/build-01/configure

Comment: Install [Least Load](https://plugins.jenkins.io/leastload/) plugin. By default, jobs go to first available match and are "sticky".

Answer (score 0):

Do you have labels on those nodes? Typically you'd see [labels](https://plugins.jenkins.io/nodelabelparameter/) being utilized for this situation and Jenkins would schedule based on available nodes.

Comment: OP indicated all nodes are labelled. As noted Jenkins [jobs are node sticky](https://plugins.jenkins.io/leastload/#plugin-content-overview).